# Adding to MongoDB a new shard. How to minimize Impact on server loads

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

Is the possible to minimize Impact on server loads while adding to MongoDB 4.2 a new shard?

I have found this recommendation. It could help but I sure should be few more thing which we can do.

> Prior to a new shard, I would first explore setting your read
>   preference to SecondaryPreferred. This will allow your primary node in
>   each RS to leverage more resources for Write operations. (c) lost

Thanks

Comment: Pointer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600680/mongodb-add-shard-to-existing-cluster-what-happens